# Python uvicorn : The term 'uvicorn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

Good evening,

I am using python 3.9 and try to run a new FastAPI service on Windows 10 Pro based on the documentation on internet https://www.uvicorn.org/ i executed the following statements

```
pip install uvicorn pip install uvicorn[standard]
```

create the sample file app.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

But when i run the code below :

```
uvicorn main:app --reload


uvicorn : The term 'uvicorn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify t
hat the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ uvicorn
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (uvicorn:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I also add the path of Python in the envroment settings

I also re-install Python 3.9  and make the default path for installation to c:\ProgramFiles\Python39 this path is also include now in the system enviroment and user enviroment settings.

[image]

if i run pip install uvicorn again it shows the following statement:

```
λ pip install uvicorn
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: uvicorn in c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (0.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: h11>=0.8 in c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from uvicorn) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click==7.* in c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from uvicorn) (7.1.2)
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 20.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Many thanks

Erik

Comment: Try adding `\pip` to the end of that path.

Comment: @John:  I did what you say! But it does not solve the problem yet! See adjusted question

Comment: Hmm.  Try `%APPDATA%\Python` instead?

Comment: @John thanks for the fast reply. It is still not working. I have changed the question again

Comment: Have you tried installing it with `pip3 install ...` ?

Comment: Hi Isabi, yes I also tried that, but that didn't work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python installs it's scripts in the scripts folder at the following path: c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\python\python39\scripts
Place that path in the system and user environment variable. This will solve the problem.

Answer (score 67):

You can also run `uvicorn` with the following command:

```
python -m uvicorn main:app --reload
```

Comment: if python does not work use python3 instead

Answer (score 5):

first, you have to run

> virtualenv env

then install code

> pip install fastapi uvicorn

Answer (score 3):

I Have The Same Problem and Found i **dont Activate** my **Virtual Environment**

After Activating **Virtual Environment** `uvicorn Example:app --reload` Worked For me

Maybe The Problem is so simple Like This

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem when using a virtual environment in Windows, so the easiest to solve this problem is in the terminal typing with `python -m uvicorn main:app --reload` after already activate that environment with `activate xxx`.
This is working!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

> pip uninstall uvicorn

then

> pip install --user uvicorn

This literarily solved the same problem on my machine.

Comment: Hi Ognyan! thanks for the reply of the solution. I found the solution of this problem. And it is in system path variable. It seams that Python install the script s in c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\python\python39\scripts\

Comment: But thanks to the removal script a saw where the uvicorn.exe is placed.